# Whats wrong with this original mail message?

Tags: gmail, spam, mail-server, postfix-mta

Recently I have bring up a mail server with postfix. After lots of configurations and settings such as DKIM and rDNS, unfortunately its outgoing mail messages to Gmail are still blocked from the inbox. ( get spam )

Now I don't have any idea about what to do next to make more confidence.

Here is the latest "Original message" which Gmail received from my mail server.

```
Delivered-To: myaccount@gmail.com
Received: by 10.28.175.19 with SMTP id y19csp228206wme;
        Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:00:59 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.96.164 with SMTP id dt4mr2470853wjb.28.1479996059102;
        Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:00:59 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <postmaster@mydomain.tld>
Received: from mail.mydomain.tld (mail.mydomain.tld. [1.2.3.4])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id w65si8419044wma.20.2016.11.24.06.00.57
        for <myaccount@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:00:57 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of postmaster@mydomain.tld designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.2.3.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.tld;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.tld;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of postmaster@mydomain.tld designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=postmaster@mydomain.tld;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.tld
Received: from mail.mydomain.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTP id 630ED9FAD9
    for <myaccount@gmail.com>; Thu, 24 Nov 2016 17:30:55 +0330 (IRST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mail; t=1479996055;
    bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:From;
    b=SbPcmZtuc54ZqmGYCU/O5kzKUPdN3x3qNS+EneBYPtD4HKIXCNJ4NMCT+pWEOkn5b
     9tiWWBaIuj+n4LoCLrZlNgQHWOKanUG9G5l2+wPw97ELBDaOEAtRb5PnLt+TxIP8A/
     SzK+bUwQ14DjY91bTDC3UBpgQ1QEtl+3L4VQa7N8tL1DByF4kOlB5N5oHpaRTOUHGc
     pitcJQ9rm2YdcMUD5vD6/EbMmCfiMkISkAfAuU8kakD3aQvFfXQ8XhrnRsK3gvv9pP
     1VTQnuHUTEoqjJb/nO9rpOdt7v0HSpxluTXt1qrTbBTXiIYhyvehnOoh4+a4VXm6sd
     VnTs1M29NeTDg==
Received: from inbox.mydomain.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 3C4609FA9D
    for <myaccount@gmail.com>; Thu, 24 Nov 2016 17:30:55 +0330 (IRST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mail; t=1479996055;
    bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:From;
    b=SbPcmZtuc54ZqmGYCU/O5kzKUPdN3x3qNS+EneBYPtD4HKIXCNJ4NMCT+pWEOkn5b
     9tiWWBaIuj+n4LoCLrZlNgQHWOKanUG9G5l2+wPw97ELBDaOEAtRb5PnLt+TxIP8A/
     SzK+bUwQ14DjY91bTDC3UBpgQ1QEtl+3L4VQa7N8tL1DByF4kOlB5N5oHpaRTOUHGc
     pitcJQ9rm2YdcMUD5vD6/EbMmCfiMkISkAfAuU8kakD3aQvFfXQ8XhrnRsK3gvv9pP
     1VTQnuHUTEoqjJb/nO9rpOdt7v0HSpxluTXt1qrTbBTXiIYhyvehnOoh4+a4VXm6sd
     VnTs1M29NeTDg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 17:30:55 +0330
From: postmaster@mydomain.tld
To: =?UTF-8?Q?=D8=B4=D8=A8=DA=A9=D9=87_=D9=87=D9=85=D8=B1=D8=A7=D9=87_?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=D8=AF=D8=A7=D9=86=D8=B4?= <myaccount@gmail.com>
Subject: DKIM algorithm with 2048 key
Message-ID: <f972c815be38cdafa49e5e645a9a6b65@mydomain.tld>
X-Sender: postmaster@mydomain.tld
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.1.6
X-AV-Checked: ClamAV using ClamSMTP

TEST
```

and sending to **verifier-feedback@port25.com** responded with this report:

```
This message is an automatic response from Port25's authentication verifier
service at verifier.port25.com.  The service allows email senders to perform
a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided
free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While
it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at
<verifier-feedback@port25.com>.

Thank you for using the verifier,

The Port25 Solutions, Inc. team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
DKIM check:         pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname:  mail.mydomain.tld
Source IP:      1.2.3.4
mail-from:      postmaster@mydomain.tld

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass 
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=postmaster@mydomain.tld
DNS record(s):
    mydomain.tld. SPF (no records)
    mydomain.tld. 14400 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.2.3.100 ~all"
    mydomain.tld. 14400 IN A 1.2.3.100
    mydomain.tld. 14400 IN MX 10 mail.mydomain.tld.
    mail.mydomain.tld. 14400 IN A 1.2.3.4

----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=postmaster@mydomain.tld
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: postmaster@mydomain.tld)
ID(s) verified: header.d=mydomain.tld
Canonicalized Headers:
    date:Thu,'20'24'20'Nov'20'2016'20'13:33:53'20'+0330'0D''0A'
    from:postmaster@mydomain.tld'0D''0A'
    to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:DKIM'20'algorithm'20'with'20'2048'20'key'0D''0A'
    in-reply-to:<cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>'0D''0A'
    references:<cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=mydomain.tld;'20's=mail;'20't=1479981833;'20'bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;'20'h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References:From;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    TEST'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    mail._domainkey.mydomain.tld. 14400 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArPpOXRz6vYf19XExCZ528I7s3EOR4YJYdsq0w8QQhbd8coDXOTpoK8rdMhcgvX+X/fvP2R9uEBP7y2U53Y312CsP4vfrAFUIRvqP28PGeN55dpCtfN603xURrTp4ee0qPkdC3N3aVrbnHLgDOiFZcrncHAXkOc7H1dsMs6ARj+qLrRjyrj7+MyCw6R49exhC0bhoHTuglhd7zivVKytt/ySaUZANDKBKFhLWATBLAHS98PtYWVieTeSA2oDCn+IKgDD5RZYECNe0VXhbMh+hrbpcKfsmZWsCtx0PH+Aoe22idd241vkkp4MZqqwY8nsb0uYmCKZgcTB8teMgzz1bfwIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: mail._domainkey.mydomain.tld (2048 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: postmaster@mydomain.tld)
ID(s) verified: header.d=mydomain.tld
Canonicalized Headers:
    date:Thu,'20'24'20'Nov'20'2016'20'13:33:53'20'+0330'0D''0A'
    from:postmaster@mydomain.tld'0D''0A'
    to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:DKIM'20'algorithm'20'with'20'2048'20'key'0D''0A'
    in-reply-to:<cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>'0D''0A'
    references:<cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=mydomain.tld;'20's=mail;'20't=1479981833;'20'bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;'20'h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References:From;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    TEST'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    mail._domainkey.mydomain.tld. 14400 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArPpOXRz6vYf19XExCZ528I7s3EOR4YJYdsq0w8QQhbd8coDXOTpoK8rdMhcgvX+X/fvP2R9uEBP7y2U53Y312CsP4vfrAFUIRvqP28PGeN55dpCtfN603xURrTp4ee0qPkdC3N3aVrbnHLgDOiFZcrncHAXkOc7H1dsMs6ARj+qLrRjyrj7+MyCw6R49exhC0bhoHTuglhd7zivVKytt/ySaUZANDKBKFhLWATBLAHS98PtYWVieTeSA2oDCn+IKgDD5RZYECNe0VXhbMh+hrbpcKfsmZWsCtx0PH+Aoe22idd241vkkp4MZqqwY8nsb0uYmCKZgcTB8teMgzz1bfwIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: mail._domainkey.mydomain.tld (2048 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result:         ham  (-3.8 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-2.9 RP_MATCHES_RCVD        Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                            domain
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 1.1 BODY_SINGLE_WORD       Message body is only one word (no spaces)

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (from RFC 5451)
==========================================================

SPF and Sender-ID Results
=========================

"none"
      No policy records were published at the sender's DNS domain.

"neutral"
      The sender's ADMD has asserted that it cannot or does not
      want to assert whether or not the sending IP address is authorized
      to send mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"pass"
      The client is authorized by the sender's ADMD to inject or
      relay mail on behalf of the sender's DNS domain.

"policy"
     The client is authorized to inject or relay mail on behalf
      of the sender's DNS domain according to the authentication
      method's algorithm, but local policy dictates that the result is
      unacceptable.

"fail"
      This client is explicitly not authorized to inject or
      relay mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"softfail"
      The sender's ADMD believes the client was not authorized
      to inject or relay mail using the sender's DNS domain, but is
      unwilling to make a strong assertion to that effect.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability to
      retrieve a policy record from DNS.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being absent or
      a syntax error in a retrieved DNS TXT record.  A later attempt is
      unlikely to produce a final result.


DKIM and DomainKeys Results
===========================

"none"
      The message was not signed.

"pass"
      The message was signed, the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, and the signature(s) passed
      verification tests.

"fail"
      The message was signed and the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, but they failed the verification
      test(s).

"policy"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures were
      not acceptable to the verifier.

"neutral"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures
      contained syntax errors or were not otherwise able to be
      processed.  This result SHOULD also be used for other
      failures not covered elsewhere in this list.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability
      to retrieve a public key.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being
      absent. A later attempt is unlikely to produce a final result.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <postmaster@mydomain.tld>
Received: from mail.mydomain.tld (1.2.3.4) by verifier.port25.com id h6qtgq20i3gp for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 24 Nov 2016 05:03:56 -0500 (envelope-from <postmaster@mydomain.tld>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=postmaster@mydomain.tld
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=postmaster@mydomain.tld
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: postmaster@mydomain.tld) header.d=mydomain.tld
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: postmaster@mydomain.tld) header.d=mydomain.tld
Received: from mail.mydomain.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTP id C4A449FA85
    for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 24 Nov 2016 13:33:53 +0330 (IRST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mail; t=1479981833;
    bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References:From;
    b=kbHJbY6k1nmQ0KmNL1ZsqQ9YP31Xdv3sfqzqJTriHrtiIO06Z4hHCsFYbrHTHL579
     tsVcPhAxLA4vxnZgASlQpYOhuJvUDe3C4EtPAjUA+9Tof1wbSeqWYFnHDHvRz4bbkP
     YKfg582YsITfw6ENEua0xKgw+ogFknWKLyeXfJXCxidO7MuNBgIWJdhYajTUmr/+WY
     yVg6D6StgiJl6tNS0U2C1qghvI/HF9wxan6+Uy8B4iTmuErzBCGly+hCbbdcl/MQOA
     sLAzh/HbsnxuOJj37QLPIpj5+dblKpAhmmR+jIQD8sAU2dCi6PvSAsYq8eOd4sgnB4
     +s9FmHfDamEJg==
Received: from inbox.mydomain.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail.mydomain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 9D4589F9B8
    for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 24 Nov 2016 13:33:53 +0330 (IRST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.tld;
    s=mail; t=1479981833;
    bh=q5cyARPl5zX/knmvCnEy11G7/r6gcljJ44qrvv5DErY=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References:From;
    b=kbHJbY6k1nmQ0KmNL1ZsqQ9YP31Xdv3sfqzqJTriHrtiIO06Z4hHCsFYbrHTHL579
     tsVcPhAxLA4vxnZgASlQpYOhuJvUDe3C4EtPAjUA+9Tof1wbSeqWYFnHDHvRz4bbkP
     YKfg582YsITfw6ENEua0xKgw+ogFknWKLyeXfJXCxidO7MuNBgIWJdhYajTUmr/+WY
     yVg6D6StgiJl6tNS0U2C1qghvI/HF9wxan6+Uy8B4iTmuErzBCGly+hCbbdcl/MQOA
     sLAzh/HbsnxuOJj37QLPIpj5+dblKpAhmmR+jIQD8sAU2dCi6PvSAsYq8eOd4sgnB4
     +s9FmHfDamEJg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 13:33:53 +0330
From: postmaster@mydomain.tld
To: check-auth@verifier.port25.com
Subject: DKIM algorithm with 2048 key
In-Reply-To: <cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>
References: <cm.0500020454906.hltjiht.jukjhkuikj.y@cmail19.com>
Message-ID: <44b3ee7e0e7d66834a3421ce97abe798@mydomain.tld>
X-Sender: postmaster@mydomain.tld
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.1.6
X-AV-Checked: ClamAV using ClamSMTP

TEST
```

Would you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Try sending a blank email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com 
It will reply with a report.  There's a section for SpamAssassin scores, which gives you some feedback on your spaminess.

Comment: @DonnLee I added the result to the question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is excited about this,
My problem was solved without any action from me after about 2 months. So I can guess that it was about my **domain reputation**. If you have the same problem I suggest you to wait for a while. In addition you can send some messages from your newly configured server to some recipient you know and you trust. Ask them to add this email address to their contacts. It will make some authority for your sever and may make the process faster.
Good luck